# Split alphanumeric string

Tags: python, string, split

I have several strings that look like

```
"Abcde fgh 123,456"
```

I want to split it as

```
["Abcde fgh", "123,456"]
```

I tried

```
string = "Abcde fgh 123,456"
re.split(r'(\d+)', string)
```

But this gives

```
["Abcde fgh", "123", "," "456"]
```

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<=\D)[ ]+(?=\d)',your_string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that result because you use a capturing group with [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=split#re.split) which will also return the captured text.

You could use a positive lookahead instead. `(?=\d)` would work, but to be more precise for your example data you could also use:

`(?<!\d)\s+(?=\d+,\d+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6TAzw/1)

```
import re
string = "Abcde fgh 123,456"
print(re.split(r'(?<!\d)\s+(?=\d+,\d+)', string))
```

Comment: @Cindy I have updated my answer by adding a negative lookbehind  `(?<!\d)`